# How to style my angular.js map ?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have built this small demo application in angular.js **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/a-maaap/)** , now if you do `ctrl+u` , you'll see that the code for the map and the marker is as follows :

```
<openlayers ol-center="center"  height="400px">
            <ol-marker ol-marker-properties="center"  message="Your current location." ng-model="center" >
            </ol-marker>
</openlayers>
```

Ofcourse that part of the HTML gets replaced once the page is loaded. Now i want my angular map to look as follows:

[image]

See the nice , centered map, with the box shadow and the border rafious , not very difficult to create in CSS.

But now in angular the HTML is replaced , so how exactly do i go about styling the HTML ? What is the convention for styling in angular.js ?

Comment: inspect the actual html generated in browser dev tools and create rules accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl , thats what i taught obviously , but that does't seem correct !

Comment: why doesn't it seem correct? Have you tried it?

Comment: @charlietfl yes that works , the other way i just found out(by myself) , is to add a wrapper and style the wrapper , but i was just wondering if this is the way its done in angular ... sorry if i sound stupid !

Comment: it's the way it's done with all html. Angular is simply generating that html